# TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'startrow'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, typeerror

I'm trying to import data from a `.csv` file and then export it to another `.csv` file. in the file I wanted to export to, there were already existing data in the same column I wanted to write. So I used the `startrow=` method to start exporting my data from the appropriate row. but as I ran the code, it raised the error

> TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'startrow'

Here's the code

import pandas as pd

```
def mokacsv(file_name):
    importing = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    column_netsales = importing['Net Sales']
    sum_of_netsales = (column_netsales)
    sum_of_netsales.to_csv('example1.csv', index=False, header=True, startrow=30)



print(mokacsv(r"example2.csv"))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, P.S this is about my second-week coding python3, I have no prior experience.

Comment: Are you trying to add data at the end of `example1.csv`? For that you should use `mode="a"`, which means "append to the file".

Comment: Yes, I am. how do you apply `mode="a"` for my code? I'm not familiar with it. thanks.

Comment: You would use it in the [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function call: `sum_of_netsales.to_csv('example1.csv', index=False, header=True, mode="a")`

Comment: I've tried it, and it worked perfectly, and I'd have to thank you. But if I may add a follow-up question, is there a way where I can add the data to certain rows (e.g row 30)? like how I originally intended to? and also at a certain column in `example1.csv` ?

Comment: I think you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69658815/edit) to ask this follow up. Which, if I understand, is: "How can I add data at a specific row in a CSV file?" You should include a [mcve] with some example input and your expected output. I'm not sure what you mean by "at a certain column" which is why the example will help clear that up.

Comment: I posted a new question instead. I figured that when I changed the original `.to_csv` to a `.to_excel` is where the parameters `startrow=` and `startcol=` work, thus solving my problem. But now I tried to `sum()` the data I've just imported and it raised an error. If you don't mind please check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `concat` function

```
import pandas as pd

one = pd.DataFrame({
   'Name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'],
   'subject_id':['sub1','sub2','sub4','sub6','sub5'],
   'Marks_scored':[98,90,87,69,78]},
   index=[1,2,3,4,5])

two = pd.DataFrame({
   'Name': ['Billy', 'Brian', 'Bran', 'Bryce', 'Betty'],
   'subject_id':['sub2','sub4','sub3','sub6','sub5'],
   'Marks_scored':[89,80,79,97,88]},
   index=[1,2,3,4,5])
print pd.concat([one,two])
```

Output:

[image]

More at [Python Pandas - Concatenation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_concatenation.htm) and [Python + Pandas: Add value to specific row in csv-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431929/python-pandas-add-value-to-specific-row-in-csv-file)